# GUI terminated with return code 4

Tags: linux

i am getting the below error .
Could you please help me resolve this

Invocation target exception: Can't connect to
 X11 window server using 'dummy0:1.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable; you 
may consider checking your DISPLAY environment variable.

Comment: Can you attached error log (output)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running remotely? I.e. over a network connection? Or are you trying to run a graphics program in the background?

Try typing   `echo $DISPLAY`

If you are on the machine itself, you should get  `:0.0`

If 'dummy' appears, then that is probably the indication that the program is trying to run in an environment without a display, and it needs one.